# How to make two releases on two different git branches by making one release

Tags: github

I have two branches of my project on GitHub.

- First branch is "**dev**" contains the main code
- Second branch is "**dev-grunt**" contains the concatenated and minified files.

There are so many folders and sub-folder containing the js files.
For example let's say that "**dev**" contains a folder "**MyApp**",this "**MyApp**" folder contains three sub-folders named as "*models*","*views*" and "*collections*".

On the other hand "**dev-grunt**" branch contains the concatenated and minified files of all the folders of dev e.g:

- The *models.min.js* is minified file of "*models*".
- The *views.min.js* is minified file of "*views*".
- The *collection.min.js* is minified file of "*collections*".

Usually we make release using **dev** branch, but now we want to make an additional release using **dev-grunt** branch.

Is it possible that we only make a release on **dev** and the **dev-grunt** branch automatically get all the changes in code from that dev release and apply these changes in minified/concatenated files and after that it should make a release?
Is it possible anyway?

Comment: No. Git doesn't know how to apply changes in the normal files to minified files. They are different sets of files, right?

Comment: Yes,you can say that if in dev branch the views folder contains 10 js files then in dev-grunt branch the code of all these 10 files is in views.min.js file which is further minified.So is there anyway to do track the changes in dev branch and apply them in dev-grunt minified files?

Comment: By minimizing them and committing them to the other branch. This is not something Git can do automatically. To Git, source code is just text. It doesn't parse it. But I wonder: a) Why in a separate branch? Since it is a different piece of code, I'd make it a separate repository. b) Why put the minified files in version control at all? After all, it's reproducable code by just re-minifying the source files you have.  I see minified files as the end product, a compiled version if you will, of the source code you have. You wouldn't add compiled executables to version control either...

Comment: a): Yes you are right,this is a good idea.I am also thinking about separate repository.
b: As we are three people in team so every one make changes at different places and push the code in github.The same procedure we want to follow for dev-grunt so that every person's changes can be saved in the minified files also.
So I will make a separate repository for minified files and then we will run grunt manually to apply changes to the minified files.Every one will follow this procedure.Please tell me am i right?Is it the right way or we have some another options?